# Error creating map in MapDB: ClassCastException: [J cannot be cast to [B

Tags: java, mapdb

I am using MapDB, and attempting to create a direct-memory map, using long-arrays as keys, and I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [J cannot be cast to [B
    at org.mapdb.Hasher$2.hashCode(Hasher.java:46)
    at org.mapdb.HTreeMap.hash(HTreeMap.java:954)
    at org.mapdb.HTreeMap.get(HTreeMap.java:390)
```

My code is:

```
Map<long[],LongBitsWrapper> inUseMap;

DB db = DBMaker
    .newMemoryDirectDB()
    .transactionDisable()
    .asyncWriteFlushDelay( 100 )
    .make();

HTreeMapMaker maker = 
    db.createHashMap( "longBitsInUseMap" )
        .hasher( Hasher.BYTE_ARRAY )
        .keySerializer( Serializer.BYTE_ARRAY );

inUseMap = maker.makeOrGet();
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot cast one type of array to another type.  Period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map keys are of type `long[]` (binary name `[J`) but you're trying to use a hasher that works with `byte[]` (`[B`). Try using `Hasher.LONG_ARRAY` instead.

Comment: That worked. I just put the wrong argument in. I also didn't realize what [J and [B meant.